# What is the version number of Oracle 18c?

Tags: oracle, oracle18c

Oracle [changed](https://blogs.oracle.com/database/oracle-database-18c-:-now-available-on-the-oracle-cloud-and-oracle-engineered-systems) the release schedule for their database, announcing that version 12.2.0.2 will be called "Oracle Database 18c."

What is the version number of the database, 12.2.0.2 or 18.x.x.x?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Comment: I need the version number to be able too have version specific code, a.k.a. conditional compilation, and to know how to tag questions in Stackoverflow. Do you remember "Oracle 8i", which was just marketing speak for version 8.1.7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Internally 18c identifies itself as version 18.**

On API level:

```
$ cat /u01/app/oracle/product/18.1.0.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/public/ociver.h
#ifndef OCIVER_ORACLE
#define OCIVER_ORACLE

#define OCI_MAJOR_VERSION 18             /* Major release version */
#define OCI_MINOR_VERSION 0              /* Minor release version */

#endif
```

And also on SQL level:

```
SQL> SELECT VERSION FROM PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION;

VERSION
----------
18.0.0.0.0
```

And also on JDBC level:

```
java -jar /u01/app/18.1.0.0/grid/jdbc/lib/ojdbc8.jar
Oracle 18.0.0.0.0 JDBC 4.2 compiled with javac 1.8.0_152 on Wed_Dec_06_05:42:32_PST_2017
#Default Connection Properties Resource
#Thu May 31 12:52:24 CEST 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, found it, the database is not yet available for download, but [livesql](https://livesql.oracle.com) says

```
SELECT * FROM v$version;

Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
```

EDIT: Hmm, the documentation for 18c is online, but it refers in the text to 12c, for instance

> 46.2 DBMS_DB_VERSION Constants
>
> The Oracle Database 12c Release 2 version of the DBMS_DB_VERSION package uses the constants shown in the following table.